# ElasticSearch Stemming (Dictionary and otherwise) plural matches singular, but nothing matches plural (PHP)

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch instance (AWS) with about 200k documents in it. Those documents feature all sorts of information, but most notably for each type there is a 'name' - by which I am mostly trying to search.

With the setup (and search) pasted below, I have a relatively successful search for most queries, provided those queries don't involve plurals. My situation at this point is, using 'stockings' (as in stocking filler) as an example:

search "stocking" - receive matches where source (name) contains "stocking" but not "stockings"

search "stockings" - receive matches where source (name) contains "stocking" but not "stockings"

search "stocking*" - receive matches where source (name) contains "stocking" and "stockings"

I believe there is something wrong with my mapping of the field to the analyzer - but I can't figure out what it is. Would be most grateful for any assistance.

```
$params = [
'index' => SEARCH2_NORMAL_INDEX,
'body' => [
    'settings' => [ 
        "analysis" => [
          "filter" => [
            "english_stop" => [
              "type" =>       "stop",
              "stopwords" =>  "_english_"
            ],
            "light_english_stemmer" => [
              "type" =>       "stemmer",
              "language" =>   "light_english" 
            ]
          ],
          "analyzer" => [
            "english" => [
              "tokenizer" =>  "standard",
              "filter" => [
                "lowercase",
                "english_stop",
                "light_english_stemmer", 
                "asciifolding"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]

    ],
    'mappings' => [
        'component' => [
            'properties' => [
              'name' => [
                'type' => 'string',
                'analyzer' => 'english'
              ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

]
];
```

and search:

```
$params = [
'index' => $indexes,
//'index' => SEARCH2_NORMAL_INDEX,
'body' => [
    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 200,
    'query' => [
        'query_string' => [
            'query' => $final_search,
            'analyzer' => 'english',
            'default_operator' => 'AND'
        ]
    ],
    'indices_boost' => [
      SEARCH2_ORDERS_INDEX => 0.5
    ]
]
];
```

Comment: You could've done this with edge ngram tokenizer also.

Comment: Your analyzer setup looks okay.  But just a thought:  if you happened to configure this analyzer without subsequently reindexing your data, the behavior would be as you describe.

Comment: Peter - thanks for your response. Every time I delete the index and recreate it, followed by manually reloading the content back into it. I'm wondering if 'english' is a bit vague / crossover of a filter name, so I'm going to try changing both the index name and the filter name and see if I have any joy.